# Can't observe flow asLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I'm learning about LiveData and Flow and I can't observe LiveData function which returns Flow.asLiveData value (readNumber() from ViewModel). Am I making some mistake?

Repository (repo):

```
var number = 0

fun readNumber(): Flow<Int>
{
    return flow {
        emit(number)
    }
}

fun setNumber(l: Int)
{
    number = l
}
```

ViewModel (mainVM):

```
fun readNumber(): LiveData<Int>
{
    return repo.readNumber().asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
}

fun setNumber(l:Int)
{
    repo.setNumber(l)
}
```

Fragment:

```
     mainVM.readNumber().observe(this){
        Log.i("DEBUGER", "number: ${it}")
    }

    binding.addButton.setOnClickListener {
        mainVM.setNumber(Random.nextInt(100))
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't"? What output do you see? Is there any error message?

Comment: You are not emitting new value inside `setNumber()`. In your case, you may want to use a [StateFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/) instead of regular flow.

Comment: 'I can't' means that observe event is not triggering when i push addButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not emitting new value inside `setNumber()`.
Use a  [StateFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/) in your case

```kotlin
var number = MutableStateFlow(0)
fun readNumber() = number.asStateFlow()
fun setNumber(l:Int) = number.update { l }
```